# Fixing type compatability for generic with hidden implementations

Tags: typescript, generics

I was trying to make a Maybe/Optional/Whatever class that could use instead of null/undefined, and I got into this weird problem where my generic class is technically type compatible with any type. My problem is that I can do

```
let a: Maybe<boolean> = Maybe.of(true);
let b: Maybe<number> = Maybe.of(1);
a = b; // No error
```

I know why this happens. My definition of Maybe has no structure to differentiate it from the others. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

```
export abstract class Maybe<T> {
  abstract map<R>(mapper: (T) => R): Maybe<R>;
  abstract flatMap<R>(mapper: (T) => Maybe<R>): Maybe<R>;
  // nothing but abstract functions
}

class Just<T> extends Maybe<T> {
    // implementation
}

class Nothing<T> extends Maybe<T> {
    // implementation
}
```

Does anyone know how you get around this? I am missing something super easy? It seems like any interface of only functions is going to have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually use `T`. The definition of `map` for example does not actually use `T` you declare a parameter named `T` not a parameter of type `T`.

```
export abstract class Maybe<T> {
  abstract map<R>(mapper: (v:T) => R): Maybe<R>;
  abstract flatMap<R>(mapper: (v:T) => Maybe<R>): Maybe<R>;
  // nothing but abstract functions
}

let a: Maybe<boolean>;
let b: Maybe<number>;
a = b; //error
```

Comment: Ok so my problem is basically I'm defining function types wrong. So what have I been doing? Did it just assume any?

map<R>(mapper: (T:any) => R): Maybe<R>;

Comment: @Buttink yup it assumed any as the type. You can use `noImplicitAny` to avoid such errors

Comment: I am so mad that I was so dumb and didn't figure this out. I thought I had `noImplicitAny` instead I had `no-any` for tslint. Thanks for pointing this out. I feel like I should apologize for wasting time lol.